# How to create confusion metrix with image dataset and h5 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

As it type in above, I'm looking the way to create confusion metrix. But all I saw is when you import image dataset from other place, not their own dataset, which make me stuck now. I tried many method but it fail. So I ask if you have a way to make confusion metrix from your own dataset and from h5 model, anything is welcome for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you want to generate a confusion matrix for a some ML model that is running on ImageNet (since a confusion matrix will be computed on the predicted output of the ML model and the ground truth from the ImageNet dataset.)
If you already have the list of predicted labels for your ML model as well as the ground truth labels, one good reference is:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html